# I am not able to use the where command for program files

Tags: cmd

i want to use
**where /r C:\Program Files (x86)\ used.cs**
but it says i can't use them! how can i use the program files x86 without that error!
please help fast

Comment: What exactly is supposed to do your where command? What exactly you would like to do? What is exactly the expected input and the output of your command?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to quote your path, otherwise `where` can't know that `Files` or `(x86)` is part of the path and `used.cs` is not!

```
where /r "C:\Program Files (x86)" used.cs
```

Comment: uhh not working! **C:\WINDOWS\system32>where /r "C:\Program Files (x86)" used.cs
INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).**

Comment: Yes so it didn't find any `used.cs` in the folder. Probably it isn't there :) Which would mean the command works as intended.

Comment: in the same bat file when i use where /r "c:\Program Files (x86)" *.cs>c:\output1.txt
it says access denied! how can i canel it for remote users who download it?

Comment: Probably your user cannot write to `c:\output1.txt`... Which is good, because you should store files only in your personal directly, not litter the `C:\ ` directory with them!

Comment: Since you are talking about other users - then you should also think about what happens when Windows or the program files directories are installed in a different place... Don't assume `C:\ ` exists at all. You should probably do something like `where /r "%PROGRAMFILES(X86)%" *.cs > "%USERPROFILE%\output1.txt"` instead then.

Comment: Also as you're talking about other users, you should also think about what happens, if they're running a 32-bit OS, as they will not generally have a `%PROGRAMFILES(X86)%` variable. And you should also note that both `%PROGRAMFILES(X86)%` and `%USERPROFILE%` are both easily modifiable variables, so may have been modified, _(delibertaly or otherwise)_, and may not point to the locations you expected them to.

Comment: OK yes in fact a batch file is an insufficient solution in that case anyway.